# filter out rows from pyspark dataframe that are 1 month ago

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I have below pyspark dataframe now

```
TIMESTAMP,TYPE,CLASS,OBJECT,INSTANCE
2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00,typeA,classA,objectA,instanceA
2022-10-22T08:39:49.1900+01:00,typeB,classB,objectB,instanceB
2022-10-18T08:37:59.3850+01:00,typeC,classC,objectC,instanceC
2021-10-11T08:37:59.3850+01:00,typeD,classD,objectD,instanceD
2022-12-01T06:40:44.3850+01:00,typeD,classD,objectD,instanceD
```

I want to filter out those rows that time is 1 month ago, so the expected dataframe should be below:

```
TIMESTAMP,TYPE,CLASS,OBJECT,INSTANCE
2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00,typeA,classA,objectA,instanceA
2022-12-01T06:40:44.3850+01:00,typeD,classD,objectD,instanceD
```

I tried below pyspark codes, but it doesn't work and can't return the expected result to me.

```
df.filter(date_format(col("TIMESTAMP"), "yyyyMM") - date_format(current_date(), "yyyyMM") > abs(1))
```

Can any expert help advice? Appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [months_between](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.months_between.html?highlight=months%20betwee#pyspark.sql.functions.months_between) to generate an additional column which can be used to filter out unwanted rows and achieve the desired results

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
TIMESTAMP,TYPE,CLASS,OBJECT,INSTANCE
2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00,typeA,classA,objectA,instanceA
2022-10-22T08:39:49.1900+01:00,typeB,classB,objectB,instanceB
2022-10-18T08:37:59.3850+01:00,typeC,classC,objectC,instanceC
2021-10-11T08:37:59.3850+01:00,typeD,classD,objectD,instanceD
2022-12-01T06:40:44.3850+01:00,typeD,classD,objectD,instanceD
""")


df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter=',')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+
|TIMESTAMP                     |TYPE |CLASS |OBJECT |INSTANCE |
+------------------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+
|2022-11-22T10:47:45.8060+01:00|typeA|classA|objectA|instanceA|
|2022-10-22T08:39:49.1900+01:00|typeB|classB|objectB|instanceB|
|2022-10-18T08:37:59.3850+01:00|typeC|classC|objectC|instanceC|
|2021-10-11T08:37:59.3850+01:00|typeD|classD|objectD|instanceD|
|2022-12-01T06:40:44.3850+01:00|typeD|classD|objectD|instanceD|
+------------------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+
```

#### Months Between

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('TIMESTAMP',F.to_timestamp(F.col('TIMESTAMP'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSS'+01:00'"))\
                .withColumn('months_diff',F.floor(F.months_between(F.current_date(),F.col('TIMESTAMP'))))

sparkDF.filter(F.col('months_diff') < 1)\
       .show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+-----------+
|TIMESTAMP              |TYPE |CLASS |OBJECT |INSTANCE |months_diff|
+-----------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+-----------+
|2022-11-22 10:47:45.806|typeA|classA|objectA|instanceA|0          |
|2022-12-01 06:40:44.385|typeD|classD|objectD|instanceD|0          |
+-----------------------+-----+------+-------+---------+-----------+
```